# How to swap the position of two buttons in android?

Tags: java, android

I am creating a a puzzle match game where in order to match two buttons together you must swap the position of them. for example, i want to swap the position of button1 with the position that button2 is in. Anybody have any suggestions?

Here is my code below:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class puzzle extends ActionBarActivity {
    private TextView moveCounter;
    private TextView feedbackText;
    private Button[] buttons;
    private Boolean bad_move=false;
  //  private static final Integer[] goal = new Integer[] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
  // private String [][] puz = new String [3][3];
   Button b [][];
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_puzzle);



        swap();

    }
    private void setBoard(){
        b = new Button[3][3];

        b[0][0]= (Button).findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b[0][1]= (Button).findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b[0][2] = (Button).FindById(R.id.button3);
        b[1][0] = (Button).FindBdyId(R.id.button4);
        b[1][1] = (Button).FindById(R.id.button5);
        b[1][2] = (Button).FindById(R.id.button6);
        b[2][0] = (Button).FindById(R.id.button7);
        b[2][1] = (Button).FindById(R.id.button8);
        b[2][2] = (Button).FindById(R.id.button9);

    }
    private void swap() {
       b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

           }
       });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_puzzle, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried for? Here you just make the reference to the Buttons and nothing more.

Comment: swap references to both buttons with each other, or the references in the parents list of children with each other, than invalidate the parents layout. This might be easier by writing a simple custom ViewGroup class extending from LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc...

Comment: I was going to use a 2d array to where one button is positioned at this index and have an if statement to swap it with the next button.

Comment: so I don't need an array? I can just use a reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using API level greater than 11, you can use getX() and getY() to get coordinates of a button.

And setX() and setY() to set a button in a particular coordinate.

for example,

```
// getting coordinates of button
float posX = button.getX();
float posY = button.getY();

// setting button2 in the coordinates that we got above
button2.setX(posX);
button2.setY(posY);
```

Comment: Okay! Thank you for the help. I will give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've gotten this work is similar to your approach you had originally posted. Try giving this a shot:

```
Button btnOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOne);
Button btnTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTwo);

float posOneX = btnOne.getX();
float posOneY = btnOne.getY();

float posTwoX = btnTwo.getX();
float posTwoY = btnTwo.getY();

btnOne.setX(posTwoX);
btnOne.setY(posTwoY);

btnTwo.setX(posOneX);
btnTwo.setY(posOneY);
```